# Creating object of parent child class together in one line?

Tags: object, constructor

I wrote this but i can't understand what is this.

```
Public ClassA {

//some methods here
}



Public ClassB extends ClassA {

Public static void main(String[] args) {

ClassA abc=new ClassB                

//What is purpose of this line and what advantage it gives us. I accidently wrote this but compiler (Eclipse not generating any error on this statement).

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You happened to stumble across the distinction of static and dynamic type for a variable and its connection to the inheritance relation.

Your variable `abc` has a static type `ClassA`. Hence the compiler will only let you use methods defined in that class on that variable. After your initialization of `abc`, it has dynamic type `ClassB`.

Since `ClassB extends ClassA`, it has every method and attribute of `ClassA` (and maybe more) and it is OK to use is through `abc`.